# Why do I have to click before the data loads?

Tags: angular, constructor

I have a problem with my Kalender. I want to load some events in it but I always have to click on it before it does. Here are some examples:

Before click: [image]

And after: [image]

(blue points are the Events of the Event Array)

My Code to fill the Event Array:

```
  initMethod() {
    return this.service
    .getEmployees()
    .pipe(tap(
    (listBooks) => {
        this.books = listBooks;
        this.events = this.books.map((book) => {
        return {
            start: new Date(book.date_from_og),
            end: new Date(book.date_to_og),
            type: ""+book.type,
            title: "" + book.device + "",
            color: colors.blue,
            actions: this.actions,
            resizable: {
            beforeStart: false,
            afterEnd: false
            },
            draggable: false
        }
        });
    }))
  }
```

My ngOnInit:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initMethod().subscribe(() => {
      if(this.events[0].start == this.books[0].date_from_og) {
          this.dialog.closeAll();
      } 
  });

  }
```

And my constructor:

```
 constructor(private modal: NgbModal, private service: BookingService, private dialog: MatDialog) {

   this.dialog.open(DialogLaedt, {
      width: '650px'
    });

  }
```

I already tried it with a Dialog, which shows up until the data gets load but this didn't work as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what component library you're using for your calendar but you could try calling your `initMethod` in `ngAfterViewInit()` instead of `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Hey @Jojofoulk, if I put this in the ngAfterViewInit method but it still the same as I put it in the ngOnInit method

Comment: Are you using an angular library for your calendar? Try calling `changeDetector.detectChanges()` in your `subscribe` method (and provide `changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef` in your constructor)

Comment: @David u're actually a god. Thanks soo much that worked!!! Please answer me with a normal answer so I can mark u as the working one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the library that you use for your calendar, but maybe something is occuring outside of the angular zone, or maybe your change detection strategy is set to `OnPush`. So you need to tell angular that something has changed and that it needs to refresh the view. For that, you can use [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

```
constructor(private modal: NgbModal, private service: BookingService, 
         private dialog: MatDialog, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
//...


ngOnInit() {
    this.initMethod().subscribe(() => {
      //...
      this.cdr.detectChanges();//Tell angular that something has changed
```